# binary tree swapping method

Tags: java, binary-tree, swap

I'm having trouble with swapping nodes between two binary trees.

I'm trying to swap the current node with the passed node in the tree, but I can't figure out how; I can only seem to swap the parents of the nodes, but not the nodes themselves.
Can anyone give me some direction?

```
    public void swap(Node node) {           
        if(this.equals(this.parent.leftChild)){
            Node tempNodeR = node.parent.rightChild;
            System.out.println("Is a left child");
            node.parent.rightChild = this.parent.leftChild;
            this.parent.leftChild = tempNodeR;
        }
        else{
            Node tempNodeL = node.parent.leftChild;
            System.out.println("Is a right child");
            node.parent.leftChild = this.parent.rightChild;
            this.parent.rightChild = tempNodeL;
        }        
    }

Calling node2.swap(node4):

Given Tree:
  1  3
 /    \
2      4

Resulting Tree (unchanged):
  1  3
 /    \
2      4

Expected Tree:
  1  3
 /    \
4      2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each node, the node has a reference to its parent and the parent has a reference to that child. So if you're going to swap two nodes, you need to update four references.

```
Tree
  1  3
 /    \
2      4
```

So here...

- 1 has a reference that points to 2 that you want to point to 4.
- 2 has a reference to 1 that should point to 3.
- 4 has a reference to 3 that should point to 1.
- 3 has a reference to 4 that should point to 2.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand the concept, but I don't understand how to swap the references of the 'this' operator's references in java, because this = node or this.parent.leftChild = node doesn't seem to have any effect.  I have a feeling I'm making some sort of trivial error here.